# Unexpected result when generating world with 2 perlin noises

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, mesh, world-design

I try to generate a world with a temperature and an humidity noise to generate biome based on the y values of the two. I take the y values and round them on a 33 base for the humidity and 25 for the temperature then add the two to get 12 possibilities of biome. to test it I first tried generating a chunk by assining the sum of humidity and temperature to their y location. I was expecting to get multiple platform at different height (12 possibilities of height) but I instead got this[image]

even if it doesn't look like it, there are random patterns within the bigger layers. i don't understand why I got that result (which looks pretty sick not gonna lie).
here is my script

```
const int seed = 50;
const int FREQUENCE = 100;
const int AMPLITUDE = 100;
const int size = 100;

int[] BIOME_DATA = { 0, 33, 66, 25, 58, 91, 50, 83, 116, 75, 108, 141 };

int[] temp_VERT = new int[100 * 100];
int[] hum_VERT = new int[100 * 100];
public int[] biome_VALUE = new int[100 * 100];

void Start()
{
    //generate the y values for the humidity vertices
    for (int x = (int)transform.position.x, i = 0 ; x < size+ (int)transform.position.x; x++)
    {
        for (int z = (int)transform.position.z; z < size+(int)transform.position.z; z++)
        {
            float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise((float)x+seed / FREQUENCE, (float)z / FREQUENCE) * AMPLITUDE;
            y = Mathf.Floor(y / 33) * 33;
            hum_VERT[i] = (int)y;
            i++;
        }
    }

    //generate the y values for the temperature vertices
    for (int x = (int)transform.position.x, i = 0; x < size+ (int)transform.position.x; x++)
    {
        for (int z = (int)transform.position.z; z < size+ (int)transform.position.z; z++)
        {
            float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise((float)x-seed / FREQUENCE, (float)z / FREQUENCE) * AMPLITUDE;
            y = Mathf.Floor(y / 25) * 25;
            temp_VERT[i] = (int)y;
            i++;
        }
    }

    //assigne une valeur représentant un biome pour chaque vertex 
    for(int i = 0; i < biome_VALUE.Length; i++)
    {
        biome_VALUE[i] = System.Array.IndexOf(BIOME_DATA, (hum_VERT[i] + temp_VERT[i]));
        //biome_VALUE[i] = new Vector2(temp_VERT[i],hum_VERT[i]);
    }

    GenerateChunk(biome_VALUE);
}

void GenerateChunk(int[] Y_VERTICES)
{
    Mesh meshy;
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    meshRenderer.sharedMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
    MeshFilter meshFilter = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

    Vector3[] VERTICES = new Vector3[Y_VERTICES.Length];
    List<Vector2> UV = new List<Vector2>();
    List<int> TRIANGLES = new List<int>();
    List<Vector3> NORMALS = new List<Vector3>();

    meshy = new Mesh();

    //création des Vecteur
    for (int i = 0, x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
        {
            VERTICES[i] = new Vector3(x+transform.position.x, BIOME_DATA[Y_VERTICES[i]], z+transform.position.z);
            i++;
            
        }
    }

    //création des normales
    for (int i = 0; i < VERTICES.Length; i++)
    {
        NORMALS.Add(-Vector3.forward);
    }

    //création des triangles
    for (int x = 0; x < size - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < size - 1; z++)
        {
            int i = size * x + z;
            TRIANGLES.Add(i);
            TRIANGLES.Add(i + 1);
            TRIANGLES.Add(i + size);
            TRIANGLES.Add(i + size + 1);
            TRIANGLES.Add(i + size);
            TRIANGLES.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    //création des uv
    for (int i = 0; i < VERTICES.Length; i++)
    {
        UV.Add(new Vector2(VERTICES[i].x, VERTICES[i].z));
    }

    //assignation des valeurs
    meshy.vertices = VERTICES;
    meshy.triangles = TRIANGLES.ToArray();
    meshy.uv = UV.ToArray();
    meshy.normals = NORMALS.ToArray();
    meshFilter.mesh = meshy;
}
```

}

Comment: Be careful of your parentheses: `(float)x+seed / FREQUENCE` is dividing only `seed` by `FREQUENCE` then adding the full value of `x`, while `(float)z / FREQUENCE` is actually dividing `z` by `FREQUENCE`. Also, the way you're using your `FREQUENCE` variable, it's acting as a *period* or *feature scale* (higher values mean wider features, more spread out), not as a *frequency* (higher values mean narrower features, closer together). Beware of misleading variable names, as they can bite you later!

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc [Mathf.PerlinNoise](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html) returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0. You multiply it by AMPLITUDE which is 100. So if you divide it by 33, you get values between 0 and 3. This is what we see in the picture.

Instead, do not multiply by AMPLITUDE and calculate

```
float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise(...);
hum_VERT[i] = (int)(33f * y);
```

Note that casting a `float` to `int` truncates the value. Therefore a call to `Mathf.Floor` is not required.

Be careful with the perlin noise values. The doc also says *"Return value might be slightly below 0.0 or beyond 1.0"*. This might lead to an index out of bounds exception somewhere else. If this happens, I suggest writing

```
hum_VERT[i] = Math.Min(32, Math.Max(0, (int)(33f * y)));
```

Assuming that the valid index range is 0 to 32 (inclusive).

---

Here is a good tutorial for [Noise, being a pseudorandom artist](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise/)

Comment: Sounds right to me! Definitely don't need to pre-divide, or use Mathf.Floor.

Comment: To add to this, @Samuel I would probably suggest not using Unity's built-in Mathf.PerlinNoise or Perlin noise in general, because it creates a lot of square bias. What I would do is look up + import FastNoiseLite (I contributed to this repo), and use either the OpenSimplex2 or OpenSimplex2S option for noise. Not only does the noise have more angular variety, its range is also properly normalized not to exceed 1. Note that its range is -1 to 1 not 0 to 1, so you'll need to do (value * 0.5f + 0.5f) if you want to use it exactly as it's used here.

Comment: Still, though, it couldn't hurt to do the min/max to be safe. And if there is something about Perlin that you like better than the Simplex type noises, then you can get most of the properties of Perlin without the square bias, by setting the 3D rotation option in FastNoiseLite to ImproveXYPlanes using the Perlin noise type, and always using the 3D noise getter GetNoise(x, y, 0).